# Reading a dynamic table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using conda 4.5.11 and python 3.6.3 to read a dynamic list, such as this:

```
[['Results:',
  '2',
  'Time:',
  '16',
  'Register #1',
  'Field1:',
  '999999999999999',
  'Field2:',
  'name',
  'Field3:',
  'some text',
  'Field4:',
  'number',
  'Fieldn:',
  'other number',
  'Register #2',
  'Field1:',
  '999999999999999',
  'Field2:',
  'name',
  'Field3:',
  'type',
  'Field4:',
  'some text'
  'FieldN:',
  'some text',
  'Register #N',
   ...
]]
```

Here is the code for my best try:

```
data = []
header = []
data_text = []
for data in res:    
    part = data.split(":")
    header_text = part[1]
    data_t = part[2]             
    header.append(header_text)  
    data_text.append(data_t)

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data_text)    
df_header = pd.DataFrame(header)
```

Output

> Field1           Field2 Field3    Field4 Fieldn1 Fieldn2 Fieldn 
>   999999999999999  name   sometext  number number  text    number 
>   999999999999999  name   sometext  number number  number  NAN 
>   999999999999999  name   number    NAN    number  text    number

Is it possible to read from a list and concat in one DataFrame?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean by dynamic? And could you please post the output you expect?

Comment: thanks! fields varies according register, i'll include the output expect.